# how to loop fadeout Need change div img

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need loop this script, but i don't know how to do this...

```
$(zaj).ready(function(){

    $("#zaj1").fadeOut(6000);
    $('#zaj2').delay(7000).fadeOut(6000);
    $('#zaj1').delay(7000).fadeIn(6000);

});
```

And I want to loop this. This is changing background img for div.

Comment: Why  loop over two items?

Comment: i have 3 divs on top. and i want fadeout 1st then shows 2nd next fadeout 2nd shows 3rd div next fadeIn 1st one

Comment: You can add function as a second parameter of fadeOut function which should be executed after first animation is done
http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Comment: It may not be the best approach, but to loop over that code you use a loop... a while or for statement...

Comment: if any of the answers were useful, don't forget to accept one ok ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(zaj).ready(function(){
   var flag = 1;
   do{
      $("#zaj1").fadeOut(6000function(){
          $('#zaj2').delay(7000).fadeOut(6000, function(){
                $('#zaj1').delay(7000).fadeIn(6000);
          });
      });

   }while(flag ==1);
});
```

but again, it do what you ask but you could find better ways... like:

```
$(zaj).ready(function(){
   setInterval(function(){
      $("#zaj1").fadeOut(6000, function(){
          $('#zaj2').fadeOut(6000, function(){
                $('#zaj1').fadeIn(6000);
          });
      });
   }, 19000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the elements to be looped through.
2. Initiate a variable for storing which element is visible now
3. Loop through using `setInterval`
4. update 'current' after each run

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
  var elements=$("#zaj1, #zaj2, #zaj3");
  current=0;
  elements.eq(current).fadeIn(6000);
  setInterval(function(){
    var next=current+1>elements.length-1?0:current+1;
    elements.eq(current).fadeOut(6000);
    elements.eq(next).fadeIn(6000);
    current=next;
  },7000);
});
```

```css
[id^=zaj]{
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="zaj1">One</div>
<div id="zaj2">Two</div>
<div id="zaj3">Three</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner code so it has clean recursive loop
https://jsfiddle.net/egwmpsa7/

```
function start() {
    $("#first").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('#second').delay(1500).fadeOut(1000);
        $('#first').delay(1500).fadeIn(1000, function() {
            $('#second').delay(1500).fadeIn(1000, start);
            setTimeout(start, 1500)
        });
    })
}
start();



<div id="first">first</div>
<div id="second">second</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
function() {
    $('#zaj1').fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('#zaj2').fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
    })           
}

$(document).ready(function(){    
   setInterval(fades, 8000);
   fades();
});
```

HTML:

```
<p id='zaj1' style="display: none;">
  zaj1
</p>
<p id='zaj2' style="display: none;">
  zaj2
</p>
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gjfg22bz/4/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done for quick scaling as you add more possible images. All you have to do is customize the variables here at the top, and you're done. The function will handle the rest.

```
var images = ['#zaj1', '#zaj2']; // Add as many as you want
var delayTime = 1000; // The time the image shows before starting the fade process
var fadeTime = 6000; // How fast the fadein/out should happen
var currentIndex = 0;

function loopOverImages() {

    $(images[currentIndex]).delay(delayTime).fadeOut(fadeTime, function () {

        ++currentIndex;
        if (currentIndex == images.length) {
            currentIndex = 0;
        }

        $(images[currentIndex]).fadeIn(fadeTime, loopOverImages);
    });
}

loopOverImages(); // Call immediately to start the process
```

Check out the really simple code snippet to help illustrate how simple this can be:

```js
var images = ['#zaj1', '#zaj2', '#zaj3'];
var currentIndex = 0;
var delayTime = 2000;
var fadeTime = 1000;

function loopOverImages() {

  $(images[currentIndex]).delay(delayTime).fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {

    ++currentIndex;
    if (currentIndex == images.length) {
      currentIndex = 0;
    }

    $(images[currentIndex]).fadeIn(fadeTime, loopOverImages);
  });
}

loopOverImages();
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}
#zaj1 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  display: block;
}
#zaj2 {
  background-color: #f08e86;
}
#zaj3 {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="zaj1"></div>
<div id="zaj2"></div>
<div id="zaj3"></div>
```